# Deriving the Morse Function

Tags: calculus

So I'm trying to understand the Morse function better, and I'm a little stuck on the derivation. The book I'm reading simply presents the derivation to me, but I'd also like to understand how to do it myself.

This is the function:

$$V(x) = V_0[1 - e^{-(x-x_0)/\delta}]^2 -V_0$$

The derivative (with a negative sign applied) is offered as:

$${2 * V_0 \over \delta} ([1 - e^{-(x-x_0)/\delta}]([e^{-(x-x_0)/\delta}]            $$

Would appreciate any help you guys could offer. I understand that the chain rule is applied here but when I start to do the specifics I get a little lost. Completely unsure why the third term is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use another function to make it clearer. Let $u(x) = 1 - e^{-(x-x_0)/\delta}$. Then we can write (just by substituting).

$$V(x) = V_0u(x)^2 -V_0$$

Now we get the derivative of $u$ as

$$u'(x) = \frac{1}{\delta} e^{-(x-x_0)/\delta}$$

by using the chain rule. Now we can derive $V$ by using the chain rule a second time, like

\begin{align*}
V'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (V_0u(x)^2 -V_0) = 2 V_0 u(x) u'(x) &= 2 V_0 (1 - e^{-(x-x_0)/\delta})(\frac{1}{\delta} e^{-(x-x_0)/\delta}) \\
&= {2  V_0 \over \delta} (1 - e^{-(x-x_0)/\delta})(e^{-(x-x_0)/\delta})
\end{align*}
which is the offered solution. I hope that it helps you :)